# Generating pdf from HTML using php

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation

I have used below code to generate a pdf. In below code, all the HTML content is saved in $html variable and using mpdf library html. Now in another page I want to print contents of that page, which is actually generated from a php script. How can I do this.  Is there any other function to convert content of a html page directly to pdf, without using a variable containing all html code

```
<?php
    $html = '
    <h1><a name="top"></a>mPDF</h1>
    <h2>Basic HTML Example</h2>
    This file demonstrates most of the HTML elements.
    <h3>Heading 3</h3>
    <h4>Heading 4</h4>
    <h5>Heading 5</h5>
    <h6>Heading 6</h6>
    <p>P: Nulla felis erat, imperdiet eu, ullamcorper non, nonummy quis, elit. Suspendisse potenti. Ut a eros at ligula vehicula pretium. Maecenas feugiat pede vel risus. Nulla et lectus. Fusce eleifend neque sit amet erat. Integer consectetuer nulla non orci. Morbi feugiat pulvinar dolor. Cras odio. Donec mattis, nisi id euismod auctor, neque metus pellentesque risus, at eleifend lacus sapien et risus. Phasellus metus. Phasellus feugiat, lectus ac aliquam molestie, leo lacus tincidunt turpis, vel aliquam quam odio et sapien. Mauris ante pede, auctor ac, suscipit quis, malesuada sed, nulla. Integer sit amet odio sit amet lectus luctus euismod. Donec et nulla. Sed quis orci. </p>

    <hr />

    <div><img src="tiger.wmf" style="float:right;">DIV: Proin aliquet lorem id felis. Curabitur vel libero at mauris nonummy tincidunt. Donec imperdiet. Vestibulum sem sem, lacinia vel, molestie et, laoreet eget, urna. Curabitur viverra faucibus pede. Morbi lobortis. Donec dapibus. Donec tempus. Ut arcu enim, rhoncus ac, venenatis eu, porttitor mollis, dui. Sed vitae risus. In elementum sem placerat dui. Nam tristique eros in nisl. Nulla cursus sapien non quam porta porttitor. Quisque dictum ipsum ornare tortor. Fusce ornare tempus enim. </div>
    <div><img src="klematis.jpg" style="opacity: 0.5; float: left;" />DIV: Proin aliquet lorem id felis. Curabitur vel libero at mauris nonummy tincidunt. Donec imperdiet. Vestibulum sem sem, lacinia vel, molestie et, laoreet eget, urna. Curabitur viverra faucibus pede. Morbi lobortis. Donec dapibus. Donec tempus. Ut arcu enim, rhoncus ac, venenatis eu, porttitor mollis, dui. Sed vitae risus. In elementum sem placerat dui. Nam tristique eros in nisl. Nulla cursus sapien non quam porta porttitor. Quisque dictum ipsum ornare tortor. Fusce ornare tempus enim. </div>

    <blockquote>Blockquote: Maecenas arcu justo, malesuada eu, dapibus ac, adipiscing vitae, turpis. Fusce mollis. Aliquam egestas. In purus dolor, facilisis at, fermentum nec, molestie et, metus. Maecenas arcu justo, malesuada eu, dapibus ac, adipiscing vitae, turpis. Fusce mollis. Aliquam egestas. In purus dolor, facilisis at, fermentum nec, molestie et, metus.</blockquote>

    <address>Address: Vestibulum feugiat, orci at imperdiet tincidunt, mauris erat facilisis urna, sagittis ultricies dui nisl et lectus. Sed lacinia, lectus vitae dictum sodales, elit ipsum ultrices orci, non euismod arcu diam non metus.</address>

    <pre>PRE: Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, 
    nascetur ridiculus mus. In suscipit turpis vitae odio. Integer convallis 
    dui at metus. Fusce magna. Sed sed lectus vitae enim tempor cursus. Cras 
    sed, posuere et, urna. Quisque ut leo. Aliquam interdum hendrerit tortor. 
    Vestibulum elit. Vestibulum et arcu at diam mattis commodo. Nam ipsum sem, 
    ultricies at, rutrum sit amet, posuere nec, velit. Sed molestie mollis dui.</pre>
';
include("../mpdf.php");

$mpdf=new mPDF(); 

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

From my experience you can either do what your code is doing by placing it all into a variable, or you could do the:

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML('html here line by line');
```

For each line you want to add to the pdf.

From an HTML file:

```
$sourceCode = file_get_contents("http://www.domain.com/path/to/page.html");
```

Your HTML will be stored in $sourceCode

Comment: This way is fine, but is there any other way of generating pdf only from currently loaded html page?

Comment: @user3549665 I modified the answer, sorry for the confusion. You could load it into a variable like above, then you can use mPDF to convert it to a PDF.

Comment: Can file_get_contents be used to get contents of the current file, like the file in which this method is used?

Comment: That you would need to try out, I'm unsure about that one.

Comment: No problem, I don't see why it wouldn't work but I don't know what issues you may encounter with all the extra data being on the page.

Comment: One more thing, how to include path from localhost. We need to give full path or relative path file_get_contents('/somefile.php') or file_get_contents('/localhost/some folder/somefile.php');

Comment: it would be the /localhost/somefolder/somefile.php

Comment: Since this is running in the same file that it is calling, try `file_get_contents("ajax report.php");`

Comment: Actually the page I want to print contains php code, which retrieves data from database. When I try to print contents using file_get_contents, I am getting all php tags and script in output

Comment: I would recommend that you split the function from the file and leave it with just the html and call the script separately if possible. Creating a filter to strip the PHP code from the file is beyond what I can help you with sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<?php
require('MPDF.php');

$pdf = new MPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```